# R data.table - big id's

Tags: r, data.table

can anyone explain me why this works like it works... It seems to be a problem with big numbers I think. Is there a way to fix it without casting the id column to character?

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(id = c(11111111111111, 11111111111112))
data[id == 11111111111111]
data[as.numeric(id) == 11111111111111]
data[, .N, by = id]
data[, .N, by = as.numeric(id)]
data[, .N, by = as.character(id)]
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: It is working as expected.  What is your question? `data[, .N, by = id]#
               id N
1: 11111111111111 1
2: 11111111111112 1`

Comment: I get              id N
    1: 1.111111e+13 2

Comment: I get with the first two:
             id N
1: 1.111111e+13 2
with as.character:
     as.character N
1: 11111111111111 1
2: 11111111111112 1

Comment: I am using R 3.3.2 and data.table 1.10.0.

Answer (score 0):

Set `options(scipen=20)` before running the code. This should give you the result you want

Documentation for `scipen`:

scipen: integer. 
A penalty to be applied when deciding to print numeric values in fixed or exponential notation. Positive values bias towards fixed and negative towards scientific notation: fixed notation will be preferred unless it is more than scipen digits wider.

Answer (score 0):

As [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) mentions in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397892/r-data-table-big-ids/41398467#comment69998329_41397892)

> I am using R 3.3.2 and data.table 1.10.0.

I've updated the data.table package to the version 1.10.0 and it works fine.